# COUNT Multiple Columns using GROUP BY - SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, count

I am trying to create a GROUP BY COUNT of ~30 columns in my database. The database is basically a shiftplan, where on each column a row can be assigned different shift types (denoted as a D, N, A, X, F, C, etc..).

I can use the following query to get a count of each shift type, am struggling to work out the best way to copy this across 30 more columns:

```
SELECT day1, COUNT(*) FROM shift_plan
GROUP BY day1;
```

This gives me the output:

```
day1,count
---------
D,1840
N,234
X,442
F,19
C,116
```

Which is close to what I want, I just want to carry it across to all other 30 workdays and end up with something more like this:

```
Shift,day1,day2,day3
----------------
D,1840,1594,1622
N,234,234,233
X,442,552,553
F,19,20,24
C,116,134,144
```

Thanks a lot for any advice you can give!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you want a `cross join` with a fixed list of values, then conditional aggregation:

```
select
    s.shift,
    count(*) filter(where p.day1 = s.shift) day1,
    count(*) filter(where p.day2 = s.shift) day2,
    count(*) filter(where p.day3 = s.shift) day3,
    ...
from (values ('D'), ('N'), ('X'), ('F'), ('C')) s(shift)
cross join shift_plan p
group by s.shift
```

Comment: I wasn't able to get this to work. Returns a syntax error at around 'from'. Any ideas? Sorry, mega noob to SQL at the moment

Comment: @Barnee: you need to replace the `...` with the additional columns (or remove it, and remove the last comma on the preceding line)...

Comment: haha brilliant, it was just that comma that I left in! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you use `GROUP BY`, you have to specify all the column names in the `group by` that are used in `select` and are not part of an `aggregate` function like `SUM, COUNT, MIN, MAX`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to copy the unions a bunch of times, but this would work.

```
    SELECT
     shift,
     MAX(day1) day1,
     MAX(day2) day2,
     MAX(day3) day3
 FROM
     (
         SELECT
             day1   shift,
             COUNT(*) day1,
             NULL day2,
             NULL day3
         FROM
             shift_plan
         GROUP BY
             day1
         UNION
         SELECT
             day2   shift,
             NULL day1,
             COUNT(*) day2,
             NULL day3
         FROM
             shift_plan
         GROUP BY
             day2
         UNION
         SELECT
             day3   shift,
             NULL day1,
             NULL day2,
             COUNT(*) day3
         FROM
             shift_plan
         GROUP BY
             day3
     ) z
 GROUP BY
     shift
```

Comment: Oh lawd, there must be another way. I'd have to do it with 30+ columns! Thanks for the idea tho, if all else fails!!